# OpenModelica - Limit joint position during simulation

Tags: limit, collision, modelica, openmodelica

I'm currently working with OpenModelica to implement a dynamic model of a robotic system and I would like to implement joint limitations due to some physical constraints. I got a bit lost since I'm not finding a proper solution to my problem: let's say that I have two links connected to a revolute joint (for example the DoublePendulum example within the MSL) and an unlimited rotation of the joint would end up with a collision of the links. How can I model some joint limitation in order to limit the angle of the rev joint to stay between let's say -pi/2 and +pi/2?

Moreover, Is there a way to implement collision properties to the components of my model? From what I've seen up to now most of the multibody example models let the bodies interpenetrate.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no collision detection in `Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody` and it is not straightforward to add it.

For you special case, would it be an option to use the `Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Components.ElastoBacklash` as a limit to the angle?
This will obviously get a lot more difficult even with "only" a double pendulum, but also a translational limitation should be possible using `Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.ElastoGap`.

An example (modified from the MSL's double pendulum), which limits the motion of the pendulum to negative values on the y-axis:

```
model LimitedPendulum

  extends Modelica.Icons.Example;

  inner Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.World world annotation (Placement(
    transformation(extent={{-100,-10},{-80,10}})));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Joints.Revolute revolute1(useAxisFlange=true,
    phi(fixed=true, start=-1.5707963267949),
    w(fixed=true, start=10))
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-60,-10},{-40,10}})));
  Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Components.ElastoBacklash elastoBacklash(
    c=1e6,
    d=10,
    b=3.1415926535898,
    phi_rel0=-1.5707963267949)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-60,30},{-40,50}})));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyBox boxBody1(r={0.5,0,0}, width=0.06)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-20,-10},{0,10}})));

equation 
  connect(elastoBacklash.flange_b, revolute1.axis) annotation (Line(points={{-40,40},{-40,20},{-50,20},{-50,10}}));
  connect(revolute1.support, elastoBacklash.flange_a) annotation (Line(points={{-56,10},{-56,20},{-60,20},{-60,40}}));
  connect(revolute1.frame_b, boxBody1.frame_a)
    annotation (Line(
      points={{-40,0},{-20,0}},
      color={95,95,95},
      thickness=0.5));
  connect(world.frame_b, revolute1.frame_a)
    annotation (Line(
      points={{-80,0},{-60,0}},
      color={95,95,95},
      thickness=0.5));
  annotation (
    experiment(StopTime=3),
    uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end LimitedPendulum;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This solution is certainly working with the pendulum example but I think that with some more complex models it could become more challenging. Plus I think that such a solution would add some dynamics properties to the model with are not desired in a dynamic model. Is it possible to add something like `revolute1(useAxisFlange=true, phi(fixed=true, start=-1.5707963267949, min = -3.1415926535898, max = 0)` sort of condition? thank you again

Comment: There are a couple of things to consider with min and max attributes:
1. They are by default not checked (due to performance reasons)
2. If they are checked and violated the simulation will be aborted (or at least a warning will be output)
The reason for the latter is likely, that there is no possibility to compute a generically valid reaction to a validation of the allowed range.